# Joomla 3 "Submit an article" page - how to remove "access level"

Tags: joomla

I have been struggling with this problem for a week now, please can someone help me. On the "submit an article" page which is only available for "registered users", can you disable or remove the field that allows the registered user to select an "access level"? I want it to be automatically set to "public" because normal registered users don't know what that means so will get confused by it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write a content plugin and implement the function [onContentPrepareForm](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentPrepareForm) like

```
public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {
    if (! in_array($form->getName(), array('com_content.article'))) {
        return true;
    }

    $form->removeField('access');
    return true;
}
```

and [onContentBeforeSave](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentBeforeSave)

```
public function onContentBeforeSave($context, $article, $isNew) {
    if ($context != 'com_content.article' && $context != 'com_content.form') {
        return;
    }

    $article->access = 1;
    return true;
}
```

Perhaps are some of the context names incorrect as I wrote to code out of my memory :-)